# ReactJS: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/interopRequireDefault'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I followed the tutorial in online video but I got an error code like this:

> Failed to compile 
>   `./node_modules/@material-ui/icons/Menu.js Module not found: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/interopRequireDefault' inb'C:\LocalServer\static-page\node_modules\@material-ui\icons'` 
>   This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

This is the code I write:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import ToolBar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';

class Header extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <AppBar position="fixed" style={{backgroundColor:'#2f2f2f',boxShadow:'none',padding:'10px 0px'}}>
          <ToolBar>
            <div className="header_logo">
              <div className="font_righteous header_logo_venue">The Venue</div>
              <div className="header_logo_title">MUSICAL EVENTS</div>
            </div>
            <IconButton aria-label="Menu" color="inherit" onClick={()=>console.log('open')}>
              <MenuIcon/>
            </IconButton>
          </ToolBar>
        </AppBar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Header
```

From the tutorial said that I should rename the directory from `@material-ui/core/Menu` on line 4 to `@material-ui/icons/Menu`. But when I revert back to `@material-ui/core/Menu`, the code is running, the button works, but no icon appeared.

But, from the tutorial shows that the program is running, with the icons appeared on it.

[image: It has a white hamburger button icon on the header]
It has a white hamburger button icon on the header

[image]
This is the error code when I try to change `core/Menu` to `icons/Menu`

[image: This is the result when I changed to core/Menu]
This is the result when I changed back to `core/Menu`

EDIT: The package.json I have right now:

```
{   "name": "static-page",   "version": "0.1.0",   "private": true,   "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.55",
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.4.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.9",
    "react-slick": "^0.23.1"   },   "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"   },   "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"   },   "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"   ] }
```

Comment: Could you post your `package.json` contents? I suspect you have version problems.

Comment: I already edit it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a MUI [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/12621) which states the exact same problem. The [solution](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/12621#issuecomment-415870759) is to upgrade to `@material-ui/icons@1.1.1`.

Since you have `@material-ui/icons@^1.1.0` as a dependency, deleting `node_modules` and running `npm install` again should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Have a go and try:

npm add @babel/runtime

Or upgrade babel runtime:

"@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.55"